# To validate the header name of each field of a csv file in azure blob storage using Azure data factory v2 pipelines

Tags: csv, azure-data-factory

I have a scenario where the user will upload a file with some data and a header in that file. i need to process the file and make sure that the field names in the header are correct and have no whitespaces and no special characters. 
eg. User dropped file in storage account contains the following header
[image]

i need to change it to this

[image]

How can i do this ADF v2 ?

Comment: I'm not sure ADF is the best option for this, can you provide some more detail? Is this in Blob Storage? Is this part of a larger ETL process or just validation?

Comment: Hi Joel, Actually this is a part of etl. if i find any white space in a column header i am supposed to remove it. can this be done using data flows?

Comment: Yes, during the Data Flow you can rename the columns using an expression to strip out the blanks.

Comment: Thank you, Joel. This was very helpful. I can apply the same if i want to remove any special characters also, right?

Comment: @JoelCochran how can i remove the existing mapping to apply the rule based mapping?

Comment: To the right of the existing mapping(s) is a trash can icon, that will remove the existing rule.

Comment: @JoelCochran this is working when i add a single rule to replace space but when i add another rule it does not detect. is this limited to only one rule?

Comment: Multiple rules work but can be tricky as they tend to interfere/overlap with one another. You can side step this by chaining multiple Selects together, each one defining another rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data Factory won't really do this as is, but if this is part of a larger ETL process, you can rename the columns in a Data Flow using Select.

Source:
[image]

Add a Select node and go to the "Select settings" tab. If you know the schema, you can just fix the columns manually here:
[image]

You can also use a Rule-based mapping to remove spaces from all the column names. To do this, remove all the existing mappings and add the following:
[image]
"true()" in this context means apply to all columns, and '$$' refers to the column name. The "Inspect" tab will show the updated column names:

[image]